# Using antd Select props for TreeSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I was using antd [TreeSelect](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/), which has similar look as [Select](https://ant.design/components/select/).

Now my question is the TreeSelect doesn't have `tagRender` props **documented**, however the Select has it.

Now I have used `tagRender` on TreeSelect anyway and it seems to work.
My question is: is this safe? can this behavior change if I don't update major version of antd?
*It seems tree select is based on select anyway.*

Comment: I hope you got the answer you were looking for. If you feel it didn't answer your question in the way you were looking for, please leave a comment. If you feel it did aswer your question well, you can also accept the answer. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

In general almost all AntD components have more options available than they document in the component page on https://ant.design/components.

A lot of the components are just CSS skins on top of the corresponding https://github.com/react-component, and quite often it is worthwhile to read the github docs for the underlying rc-component since they usually are more complete, and using the props available on those components is supported by AntD.

For TreeSelect you are correct that it is based on Select, and in this case specifically https://github.com/react-component/select/blob/master/src/generate.tsx for `tagRender`, so you should be fine using that.